# Marker con imagen Pixelada, Google maps Nativo Ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic2

Cuando coloco una imagen Grande como marcador no puedo redimensionarla y se ve muy grande en el mapa, y cuando coloco una pequeña se ve pixelada, Ayuda !

Hay alguna forma de cambiarle el tamaño a una imagen con buena resolucion.

```
let icon = 'www/assets/images/car3.png';
let position: GoogleMapsLatLng = new GoogleMapsLatLng(0,0);
let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
  position: position,
  icon:icon
};
```

Answer (score 0):

En google maps API puro y duro, la definición de un ícono podría ser como la tienes tú:

```
let iconimg = 'www/assets/images/car3.png';

let markerOptions = {
   position:position,
   icon: iconimg
};
```

Pero eso es sólo una manera corta de declarar:

```
let iconimg = 'www/assets/images/car3.png';

let markerOptions = {
   position:position,
   icon: {
           url: iconimg,
           size: new google.Maps.Size(24,24),
           scaledSize: new google.Maps.Size(32,32)
         }
};
```

Y eso te permite jugar con el tamaño final de tu ícono sin tener que cambiar la imagen.

Ahora sólo tienes que encontrar cómo adaptar ese código a Ionic.

Comment: Esto que tu propones no esta disponible en la librería de Google maps para angular 2 (Typescript). En realidad lo que quiero es un parche donde se pueda adaptar eso, así como dices al final.